# How to remove a package from defpackage?

Tags: error-handling, package, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I defined a package like this:

```lisp
(defpackage :web-app
  (:nicknames :wa)
  (:use :cl :hunchentoot))
```

This works fine.

But I want to remove hunchentoot. When I remove it and recompile I get the following error:

```
Unknown location:
  warning: 
    WEB-APP also uses the following packages:
      (HUNCHENTOOT)
    See also:
      Common Lisp Hyperspec, DEFPACKAGE [:macro]
      SBCL Manual, *ON-PACKAGE-VARIANCE* [:variable]
```

How do I remove packages from my lisp image in these cases.

I have tried restarting the image but no luck.

Comment: This error can only happen if you're redefining a package that already exists. So you must be loading the package definition into an image that had the previous definition. Make sure you recompiled everything that depends on the package definition.

Comment: mmm, this might be the case. Question, how do i remove previous packages that I do not want anymore completely?

Comment: You can use `DELETE-PACKAGE` to remove a package from the image.

Comment: Yes, this was the correct answer. Thank you Barmar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the function to use is [unuse-package](http://l1sp.org/cl/unuse-package). For example:

```
(unuse-package :hunchentoot :web-app)
```

That will sync the package system with your defpackage form so it will re-evaluate without a warning.